# react is not updating components using state in class

Tags: reactjs

so first of all I am trying to assign null values to the state component and then assign them values later so here is my constructor of a class

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Countrys:null,
            States:null,
            Citys:null
        }
    }
```

and then I am asigning them value is ComponentDidUpdate function so here is my componentDidMount function

```
componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          console.log(position)
          console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
          console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
        });
        this.setState({
          Countrys:Country.getAllCountries(),
            States:State.getAllStates(),
            Citys:City.getAllCities()
        })
        
        /*console.log("Country:: "+Country.getAllCountries()[0].name);
        console.log("City:: "+City.getAllCities()[0].name);*/

      }
```

and then I am  trying to access them in my jsx elements in return using map like this

```
 {this.state.Citys.map((ele ,index) =>
          <option value={`${ele}`} className="d-inline mx-2 col-sm-5" onClick={({target}) => target.classList.toggle('bg-primary')}>
          {ele.name}
         </option>
      )}
```

but its showing me error that

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong here or how to correct it
and when I am trying to assign City.getAllCities() like functions directly to this.state instead of assigning them with null it shows me page unresponsive

And City.getAllCities(), Country.getAllCountries(), State.getAllStates() are from npm package "country-state-city"

Comment: Your constructor initialize the states to null, so on that first render, you get the error. Setting in ComponentDidMount causes a second render, it doesn't set the initial value. Either check for null before trying to map it, or initialize the state to an array.

Comment: Also, on a JS convention note: variables use camelCase (lowercase first letter), classes use CamelCase (uppercase first letter), so you definitely want to change that to `state = { countries: null, states: null, cities: null }` instead. Though: why are you assigning those values in `componentDidMount` instead of in the constructor? I don't see you fetching using some kind of async I/O, so presumably those `Country`, `State` and `City` objects already exist: just tap into them in the constructor's state assignment?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans just go through the last few lines of question again Country State and City are from npm package "country-state-city"  I mean its fetching data from that package server

Comment: What "server"? Node modules are static (and in this case https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city clearly shows this is static data that you just load directly) and any bundling utility (esbuild, rollup, webpack, etc) will directly bundle them in, so I still don't see why you're doing this in `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, like you mentioned, you're using [country-state-city](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city), then there is no reason to defer loading those three values until `componentDidMount` at all: they're static imports from the `country-state-city` package.

Just import them at the top of your file, create your initial state in your constructor, assign those values, and you're done without any `null` states during render.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Country, State, City }  from "country-state-city";
...

export class YourClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countries: Country.getAllCountries(),
      states: State.getAllStates(),
      cities: City.getAllCities()
    };
  }

  render() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first render will have state.Citys set to null, as you've set in the constructor.

ComponentDidMount will only fire after the first render.

you should initialized the state in the constructor

Comment: I am trying to do that but itz showing me page unresponsive in chrome, since its taking to mutch time to fetch data

Comment: then prepare your render funcion to deal with the null value for your state, showing a loading spinner or a blank page if the state is null.

Comment: for example: in the line above the return, you can add `if(!this.state.Citys) return null`

Comment: @Bernado Ferreira Bastos Braga You mean that I can call a loading function using render using the render with above condition??

Comment: I mean you can have a conditional render for the loading state.
In the constructor, your state is null. You told me that the state fetched in componentDidMount takes a while to fetch. Then you can opt to render something else while the state loads.

Comment: in other words, if the state is null, you'll render null or "Loading...". Else, go on with your code `this.state.Citys.map(...`

Comment: Then that probably has to do with the API you're using to fetch the state. For example, try setting a dummy value to the Citys object in componentDidMount, such as `Citys: ['a','b','c']`. If that works, it's not a react issue

Answer (score 0):

As [Bernardo Ferreira Bastos Braga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351652/bernardo-ferreira-bastos-braga) mentioned, `state.Citys` is null in the first render.
One thing you can do to avoid the error is to render conditionally.

```js
 {this.state.Citys !== null && this.state.Citys.map((ele ,index) =>
          <option value={`${ele}`} className="d-inline mx-2 col-sm-5" onClick={({target}) => target.classList.toggle('bg-primary')}>
          {ele.name}
         </option>
      )}
```

Or

```js
 {this.state.Citys === null ? <SomeOtherComponent/Element/EmptyFragment/etc.. /> : this.state.Citys.map((ele ,index) =>
          <option value={`${ele}`} className="d-inline mx-2 col-sm-5" onClick={({target}) => target.classList.toggle('bg-primary')}>
          {ele.name}
         </option>
      )}
```

In these examples, the map function won't be called if `state.Citys` is null.